# JComboBox change displayed text every time any change is made

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I am trying to edit the displayed text (in the JComboBox itself, not the dropdown popup of options) every single time that any option is clicked/changed.

I have a custom renderer that looks kind of like the one below:

```
JComboBox<Object> jc = new JComboBox<Object>();
jc.setRenderer(new ListCellRenderer<Object>() {
    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<? extends Item> list,
                                                  Object value, int index, 
                                                  boolean isSelected,
                                                  boolean cellHasFocus) {
        if(index == -1)
            return new JLabel("this is the top cell");

        return new JLabel("this is a cell in the dropdown popup area");
    }
});
```

This successfully changes the text whenever the renderer is called. The trouble is that this renderer is not called every time an entry is clicked.

I have tried to make a custom event call in my class that extends JComboBox, but when trying to call a change, I'm not sure how to specify that I only want to change the top text (and leave the rest of the dropdown cells alone). I have been messing with the method:

```
fireItemStateChanged(new ItemEvent(this,ItemEvent.ITEM_STATE_CHANGED,
                                               somethingGoesHere,
                                               ItemEvent.DESELECTED));
```

but I can't figure out what item Object to put in place of `somethingGoesHere` to specify to call for a re-render to the top text. None of the entries in `dataModule.getElementAt(int index)` seem to create a call to change the correct text.

(My extending class of JComboBox has made large-ish changes including making the dropdown popup not automatically hide when an option is clicked, which is probably why the top text doesn't change as often as expected and I am trying to call the renderer on my own.)

EDIT:

After a bit of testing, the problem is that I want the JComboBox display bit to refresh even if the dropdown item that was previously selected is clicked again.

I tried overriding `setSelectedItem(Object anObject)` to call `selectedItemChanged()` even when `selectedItemReminder == dataModule.getSelectedItem()`, but this doesn't then force an update of the JComboBox display text. :(

Comment: You probably should not use a JComboBox for this.  Consider using a JButton and your own JPopupMenu instead.

Comment: A JPopupMenu or JList would probably do what I'm trying to do a lot easier, but for unrelated reasons it's strongly preferable that it look/feel like a JComboBox. I was hoping I could make a workable extension of JComboBox, but if it's actually impossible I'll give up and swap to a JPopupMenu. (I've fixed every problem *except* that I can't get this top cell to refresh)

Comment: A combo-box has a specific function—selecting one of many values—but I’m pretty sure you’re using it for a different function, namely menu-like functionality.  I don’t think a combo-box is the best choice here.  (JavaFX actually has a [MenuButton](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/MenuButton.html) class for this.)

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out!

The event I needed to explicitly call was `fireContentsChanged(this, -1, -1)` within the DefaultComboBoxModel, so I extended *that* class into a custom model so my extension of JComboBox could tell the model to run that method. This successfully forces the ListCellRenderer to update the display text I'm trying to change.

The [DefaultComboBoxModel](https://github.com/openjdk/shenandoah/blob/master/src/java.desktop/share/classes/javax/swing/DefaultComboBoxModel.java) usually is the one that calls for updates to the display text of the JComboBox from the model's `setSelectedItem(Object anObject)` method.